# Is there any way to reorder the nodes in a View?

Tags: 7, views

I have a complicated View containing many pages and attachments. When I built the View, I didn't think much about the order of the pages and attachments, but now I would like to change the ordering because it affects how they are displayed in the end. I would also like the flexibility to add additional pages in the future and be able to control where those attachments appear in the page.

I know you can control an attachment's position using the Above/Below options, but I have one page with 6 attachments and I can't seem to break the ordering except by creating and deleting nodes.

**Edit**: I discovered that I can accomplish this by exporting the View and reordering the code there and then reimporting, but if a cleaner solution exists, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 9):

You may also consider using the [draggableviews](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module. Basically you create an "administrative" display of your view allowing arbitrary reordering of the content of the "main" display using drupal drag-and-drop interface.

There's also a [comparison page](http://drupal.org/node/398508) for node ordering modules on drupal.org

Answer (score 6):

You can ues the [Nodequeue](https://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) module. Nodequeue allows you to create and arbitrarily sort "queues" of nodes and it integrates with the Views module.

> The Nodequeue module allows users to collect nodes in an arbitrarily ordered list. The order in the list can be used for a any purpose, such as:
>
> - A block listing teasers for the five top news stories on a site
> - A user’s favorite music albums
> - A group of favorite from which one is randomly displayed
>
> Nodequeue provides a simple drag-and-drop interface to manually order any queue.