# views of node with weight

Tags: views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add a “weight” functionalitiy to nodes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4789/how-can-i-add-a-weight-functionalitiy-to-nodes)

I have views of node for example 10 last of news,I want when create a views of node , I can set this weight, means that create own list.
for example , I chose first node , second node ...

please help me

Comment: ...and also of [Is there any way to reorder the nodes in a View?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/is-there-any-way-to-reorder-the-nodes-in-a-view)

Answer (score 0):

You should extend your contenttype with a weight field for this and use it as sort parameter. If your drupalversion is 6 you could use the [CCK module](http://drupal.org/project/cck) for that.

Comment: I want create own list and handle my list for example with drag and drod